# Find min/max values in a multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, max, min

I need to find the minimum and maximum in a multidimensional array in PHP, I have what I thought would work below but it keeps giving me a parse error, this is homework and I am not asking anyone to do it for me but I am a beginner and any help would be appreciated.

```
<?php

/* 2 dimensional array in PHP - strictly an array of arrays */

$multable[] = array("11", "12", "15", "22", "41", "42");  
$multable[] = array("6", "7", "16", "17", "22", "23");  
$multable[] = array("1", "15", "16", "20", "22", "3");  

<table>
<?php
/* display a table from a 2D array */
for ($j=0;$j<3;$j++) {
    print "<tr>";
    for ($k=0;$k<6;$k++) {
        echo "<td>",$multable[$j][$k],"</td>";
    }
    print "</tr>";
    $max_value = 0;
    foreach ($multable as $myMax) {
        if ($max_value<$myMax) {
            $max_value = $myMax;
        }
    }
echo $max_value;
?>
</table>
```

Answer (score 7):

There is also a one-liner for that:

```
$max = max( array_map("max", $multable) );
```

Answer (score 1):

use `max()` and `min()` functions of php.

Comment: see doc as php.net and try yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Max:

```
<?php
$multable = array();
$multable[] = array("11", "12", "15", "22", "41", "42");  
$multable[] = array("6", "7", "16", "17", "22", "23");  
$multable[] = array("1", "15", "16", "20", "22", "3");  
$max = -99999999;
foreach($multable as $sub){

  $tempMax = max($sub);

  if($tempMax > $max){
    $max = $tempMax;
  }

}

echo $max;

?>
```

You can figure out min :)

Answer (score 0):

Your `foreach` iteration only does one dimension - each `$myMax` is one of your six element lists and not an individual scalar value.  That's why your comparison doesn't work and the conditional is never true, you are trying to compare a scalar with an array. What you call `$myMax` would more appropriately be called `$currentRow`

This is ok because PHP has some functions to find the min and max of an array

http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.min.php
http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.max.php

```
$max_value = 0; $min_value = $multable[0][0];
foreach ($multable as $currentRow) 
{
    // COMPARE CURRENT ROW's MIN/MAX TO MIN/MAX_VALUE 
    // AND MAKE NEW ASSIGNMENT IF APPROPRIATE
}
```

Or hand this in and see what your teacher says:

```
function fComp ($f) {return function ($a,$b) use ($f) {return $f($a, $f($b));};}

$max = array_reduce($multable, fComp('max'), $multable[0][0]);
$min = array_reduce($multable, fComp('min'), $multable[0][0]);

echo "max: $max <br />";
echo "min: $min";
```

PS - in your earlier iterations to make the HTML table, it would be good form to lose the constants.  Use `count` to get the length of the array instead - or better yet - use `foreach` like you do later on.  (Even with `foreach` you would still need two of them nested, it doesn't iterate a 2-dimensional array element-by-element)

Comment: I was reading about array_reduce which reduces the array to one number but couldn't figure out how to insert the min max portion but this really explains it, thanks

Comment: this is a kind of tricky example.  using it to sum an array would be the easiest introduction.  this is weird because one argument is a scalar and the other is an array, and i use both overloaded versions of min/max.  check out some more straightforward `array_reduce` here http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.array-reduce.php

Answer (score 0):

For Minimum value

```
echo min(array_map("min", $multable));
```

For Maximum Value

```
echo max(array_map("max", $multable));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$minArray = array();
        foreach($arrayVal as $arrI=> $arrK)
        {

            if($arrK == min($arrayVal ) )
            {
                array_push($minArray , $arrayVal );
            }
        }

print_r($minArray);
```

Here you go :)

Answer (score 0):

I do not recommend calling `min()` or `max()` on each subarray, then calling the function again on the reduced array.  This is making too many calls and won't be most efficient.

Instead, flatten the indexed array just once with a spread&merge technique, then call `min()` or `max()` just once on the flattened array.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/YYNU6))

```
$flat = array_merge(...$multable);

printf(
    'Min: %d, Max: %d',
    min($flat),
    max($flat)
);
```

Output:

```
Min: 1, Max: 42
```

If you only need one or the other outcome, then don't bother with the temporary variable.

```
echo min(array_merge(...$multable));
```

Or

```
echo max(array_merge(...$multable));
```