# radio checked lowest value in blade

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

The following is my laravel blade code. I want automatically check the radio with lowest value.

```
{
    @foreach($service_stages as $ss)
        <input class="" id="money" name="money" type="radio" id="" value="{{$ss->money}}" onclick="generateDate()" checked>{{$ss->money}}
    @endforeach
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First write some code to find the smallest value (e.g. in your controller). Then save it to a variable which you provide to your blade view. Lets assume you have it in the variable `$smallestValue` then you can try the following:

```
@foreach($service_stages as $ss)
    {{ Form::radio('money', $ss->money, ($ss->money == $smallestValue) ? true : false , ['id' => 'money', 'onclick' => 'generateDate()']) }}
@endforeach
```

This will set the `checked="checked"` if `$ss->money == $smallestValue`.

Comment: Following it's my code in controller and output. How can I get $smallestValue = 300 from this array.

'$service_stages = DB::table('service_stage')->where('money', '>', 0)->get();
   print_r("<pre>");
   print_r($service_stages);
   print_r("<pre>");
   exit();'

Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 2
            [money] => 300
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 3
            [money] => 500
        )

    [2] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 4
            [money] => 800
        )
)

Comment: Sorry but this spaghetti code is almost unreadable. But you can walk through each array item and check if its value is lower than the actual lowest one. Or use the `min` function in combination with `array_map`. This part of the question was solved here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5334955/php-find-min-max-in-a-multidimensional-array